# Generating random strings from a string-pool using QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, quickcheck, state-monad

Consider the problem of generating strings out our a set of possible strings, in such a way that once a string is chosen, it cannot be repeated again. For this task I would like to use `QuickCheck`'s `Gen` functions.

If I look at the type of the function I'm trying to write, it looks pretty much like a state monad. Since I'm using another monad, namely `Gen` , inside the state monad. I wrote my first attempt using `StateT`.

```
arbitraryStringS :: StateT GenState Gen String
arbitraryStringS =
  mapStateT stringGenS get
```

where:

```
newtype GenState = St {getStrings :: [String]}
  deriving (Show)

removeString :: String -> GenState -> GenState
removeString str (St xs) = St $ delete str xs

stringGenS ::  Gen (a, GenState) -> Gen (String, GenState)
stringGenS genStSt =
  genStSt >>= \(_, st) ->
  elements (getStrings st) >>= \str ->
  return (str, removeString str st)
```

Something that troubles me about this implementation is the fact that I'm  not using the first element of `stringGenS`. Secondly, my end goal is to define a random generator for JSON values, that make use of a resource pool (which contains not only strings). Using `StateT` led me to implement "stateful" variants of `QuickCheck`'s `elements`, `listOf`, etc.

I was wondering whether there's a better way of achieving this, or such a complexity is inherent to defining stateful variants of existing monads.

Comment: I would do it the other way - to store the created `Strings` - or at least the seeds and compare each seed/generated string for membership in a `Set` of seeds/`String`.

Comment: another choice could be using uuid's to generate "most probably" unique strings, if you only have a finite set of strings - you eventually run out of strings, you could work around by making combinations of big base sets - but still you will run into duplicate strings - if you need "real uniqueness" I'd go with a base set + an infinite set like the natural numbers and combine that.

Comment: It is important that the strings come from the resource pool. This can be used to generate tests using data existing in some database.

Comment: (1) Why must be the generated strings unique? This doesn't sound like a standard testing use-case. (2) Why do you want to use the `Gen` monad? Perhaps the [random monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html) would work better.

Comment: Forget about the uniqueness requirement. I just edited my answer. Then we can focus on generating random objects from a resource pool.

About (2). I haven't consider this yet. But I'm curious on how to combine `Gen` with `StateT`.  Besides using `Gen`,  I can make use of its functions like `elements`, `listOf`, etc.

Comment: Is [`shuffle :: [a] -> Gen [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:shuffle) not exactly what you want? What exactly is the purpose of the `State`? You can get away with just `Reader` here.

Comment: This problem arises in a more complex context, where I need to generate random data for objects that have hierarchical dependencies. For instance, if I need to generate an object containing an artist and an album, once I chose the artist, I can only generate albums from that artist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of `StateT` and `Gen` could look like this:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.List (delete)
import Test.QuickCheck

-- A more efficient solution would be to use Data.Set.
-- Even better, Data.Trie and ByteStrings:
-- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-trie-0.2.4.1/docs/Data-Trie.html
newtype GenState = St { getStrings :: [String] }
  deriving (Show)

removeString :: String -> GenState -> GenState
removeString str (St xs) = St $ delete str xs

stringGenS :: StateT GenState Gen String
stringGenS = do
  s <- get
  str <- lift $ elements (getStrings s)
  modify $ removeString str
  return str
```

The problem is that as you need the state, you can't run multiple such computations in `Gen` while sharing the state. The only reasonable thing to do would be to generate multiple random unique strings together (using the same state) as

```
evalStateT (replicateM 10 stringGenS)
```

which is of type `GenState -> Gen [String]`.

Comment: Thanks. The use of `lift` is definitely more elegant. Regarding the State, as I mentioned in my previous comment, since I need to generate data that has a hierarchical relationship, the choice of one element limits my future choices, and that is the reason why I want to pass the state from one generator to the other. The generation of strings was just illustrative.

Comment: Beware that `Gen` doesn't give you any particular distribution. As it's used for reading, it tries to catch various corner cases, rather than being uniform in any way.

Comment: Good point. I definitely need to consider this in the future. It might be that I'll end up using a `Random` monad. However I hope I can use the same technique of composing monad transformers.

Comment: MonadRandom is actually better, because unlike Gen it also provides a transformer, RandT. So you can compose also the other way around.